# Installing Ubuntu 20.04 on Asus tuf-fx550gt

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, asus

I am planning to install 20.04 along side with the windows 10 in Asus tuf-fx550gt and there is a concern that my hard disk (NVme PCIE card) won't support for the system. I cannot remove windows completely from the machine because of the warranty reasons plus i am exhausted with the windows system and need help figuring out my options.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: I need to know that is it possible to install Ubuntu after changing the HDD settings in BiOS PCI to AHCI